# Connect <div> to centre <div>

Tags: html, css

I try to connect a `div` to my centre `div` but I can't figure it out. The "connecting div" should be adjacent to the centered `div`, but the alignment of the centre `div` should not change. (It should stay in the centre.)

**HTML**

```
<div class="yelow"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.yelow{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    height:100px;
}
```

Here's the **fiddle**:

http://tinyurl.com/k2twodz

So the yellow `div` should be **adjacent** to the red centre div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the yellow on top of the red one? Use absolute positioning

Comment: No, he wants yellow to be adjacent to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I also adjusted the HTML code.
http://jsfiddle.net/hrvvvz4v/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="yelow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.yelow{
    position:relative;
    right:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible that the red div stays in the centre?

Comment: I think that he wants red to be centered, yellow to be near it. The center has to be in the center of red, not between yellow and red.

Comment: Almost! Now the red and yellow together are in the centre; so the red is slightly to the right. I need the red one to stay in perfect centre.

Comment: Without HTML changes? :)

Comment: Thanks Nath, thats it!

Comment: No, thats not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="main">
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
   .main
   {
     width:200px;
     height:100px;
   }

   .red
   {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
   }

   .yellow
   {
    float: right;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    height:100px;
    }
```